# Strange depth/blending in OpenGL drawing models

Tags: opengl, models, depth-buffer

I'm having a strange problem which I cannot figure out for the life of me. I'm loading an OBJ model file from Maya and rendering it an OpenGL environment. This appears to go well and in my independent model viewer, they display correctly. However, when loaded into the game environment (with a somewhat strange projection matrix that I have no control over), the model does NOT display correctly.

The vertices SEEM to be in the correct place in that rotating the model gives the correct sense of 3D.  However, depending on the depth function, different parts of the model appear (incorrectly).

For example, in a model of a person, when the person is walking from left to right (e.g. the right side of the model is visible to the camera); if the depth function is set to `GL_LEQUAL`, you are unable to see the right arm of the person when it is in front of the torso. However, when the mode is set to `GL_LESS`, you are able to see the left arm through the torso. This is one of those things that are easier to see with pictures so here we go:

`GL_LESS` or `GL_NOTEQUAL`:

[image]
[image]

`GL_LEQUAL` or `GL_ALWAYS`:

[image]
[image]
[image]

It should be noted that nothing is displayed with any other depth function. In the first picture of the GL_LEQUAL series, you can just about see the left arm is partially obscured by the torso when it shouldn't be.

Here is the code used to render the model:

```
gl.glDisable(GL.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    layerTextureShader.updateShader(gl, projection, disparityTop, disparityBottom, fieldMask, 1);

    // gl.glDepthFunc(GL.GL_NEVER); // 512
    // gl.glDepthFunc(GL.GL_LESS); // 513
    // gl.glDepthFunc(GL.GL_EQUAL); // 514
    // gl.glDepthFunc(GL.GL_LEQUAL); // 515
    // gl.glDepthFunc(GL.GL_GREATER); // 516
    // gl.glDepthFunc(GL.GL_NOTEQUAL); // 517
    // gl.glDepthFunc(GL.GL_GEQUAL); // 518
    // gl.glDepthFunc(GL.GL_ALWAYS); // 519
    gl.glDepthFunc(currentGlComparison);

    gl.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glClear(GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glDepthMask(true);
    gl.glDepthRange(0, 0.01);

    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, getVertexBufferObject());
    gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, getNoOfVertices() * 3 * 4, getVertices(), GL.GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, getTexCoordBufferObject());
    gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, getNoOfVertices() * 2 * 4, getTexCoords(), GL.GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, getIndicesBufferObject());
    gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, getNoOfIndices() * 4, getIndices(), GL.GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, getColorBufferObject());
    gl.glBufferData(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, getNoOfVertices() * 4 * 4, getColors(), GL.GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glActiveTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE0);

    layerTextureShader.use(gl);

   gl.glEnableClientState(GL.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, getVertexBufferObject());
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mask ? getMaskColorBufferObject() : getColorBufferObject());
    gl.glColorPointer(4, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    gl.glClientActiveTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE0);

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, getTexCoordBufferObject());
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, getIndicesBufferObject());

    final int count = getNoOfIndices();
    gl.glDrawElements(GL.GL_TRIANGLES, count, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    layerTextureShader.release(gl);

    gl.glDisable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    gl.glDisable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glEnable(GL.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
```

Thanks to anyone for any help, this has had me stumped for quite a few days now.

Comment: typically you would use LESS, but from the images, it looks like the projection matrix is "flattening" the model so all vertices are in the same depth.  would need more information about how the projection is setup to really answer this

Comment: Thanks for the insight, so would you suggest I perform some calculations (e.g. GL_Projection * GL_ModelView * GameProjectionMatrix * PointXYZ) to see what is actually being printed?

Comment: My GL_Projection matrix is an ortho2D matrix set up with a call to `gluOrtho2d(0, 1920, 0, 1080);` and the GameProjection matrix is odd as I mentioned with values `[192, 2807, 7, -2.4e7; -825, 49, -2869, -1.2e7; 0.9, -0.06, -0.29, 68059; 0, 0, 1.49e-8, -0.9]` I'm aware this is odd but it IS neccessary and other elements are displayed correctly using it (i.e. not-model elements. So I am unable to see how this would result in all Z values being flattened, but I hear I am missing something blindingly obvious...

Comment: You know, that you can switch the projection and modelview matrix anytime you want in the rendering process? If you're using those values to make up for and HUD or similar: Just set appropriate projection just for the HUD and use sane values for the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the projection matrix is set like this:

```
gluPerspective ( 90, (GLint)width/ (GLint)height, 0.0, 200.0 );
```

See the mistake ? - 0.0 value is not acceptable. Only positive values are good
Use something like 0.01 instead of 0.0 as third argument.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, the matrix is set using glFrustrum using all positive values. `gl.glFrustum(-960, 960, -540, 540, 0.01, 100);` is what I use.

Comment: The near clip plane if far to close to the origin. Also those values in glFrustum make no sense, this would give you an affine field of view of nearly 180°, it's hardly what you want.